# What datatype is best for storing articles in SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a custom CMS for my site, and I'm going to store articles (Text and images per article) in a mysql database. what datatype is best suited for that task?

Comment: Presume `TEXT` would be the best datatype for this.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason why you want to store the Images in Database, but I believe its good to keep Images on Machine's local drive and store only `path' in database. It will be good for performance. Ignore me if I'm wrong. I'm not a CMS expert. Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't try to store text and images in a single field, and in this circumstance you probably shouldn't store images in your database at all.

The best solution for this would be to use some kind of markup system in your articles - at it's simplest this could be a filtered subset of html - that is stored as plain text in your database and then parsed in the browser in some way. Obviously if you use filtered html you would not need to write any special code to parse it, but taking this approach does raise possible security issues.

Other options to investigate include Markdown (the system used by this site) as well as BBCode (mainly used by online forums), as well as many others.

To summarise - don't store images and text in one field. Store text, and interpret that text to load images and other media in your articles as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Save the images as VARCHAR, but only the image name (and/or location, depending on how big is your cms), save the text as - `TEXT`.

Answer (score 1):

In my oppinion use text for articles, containing HTML characters, thats what i use. But there are many other things to consider. It depends on what content of your articles. In your images its up to you, you will just store the path of the picture, unless you plan to store the picture itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) in which Microsoft insists the `text` datatype is going to disappear and therefore should not be used in new development. The alternatives are varchar and nvarchar for text and varbinary for images.

Answer (score 0):

Store images and text separately. Assuming you are trying to store the binary images in the database, I recommend storing images as a BLOB datatype and TEXT for the text.

Don't use VARCHAR for article text because it does not dynamically expand past the size you make it.

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR would be the best choice for storing text-articles as text and images data types would disappear in the future.

For images you can store them in  a folder similar to what you use for css/js and store its src value in the database. This would be efficient in terms of both speed and storage.